# Google Sheets: Adjusting an array formula to auto-appear in every row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The formula in question is `=IF (ISBLANK(H2),"", ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF( (MOD(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(H2))&H2,ROW($1:$31),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$31),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(H2))&H2,ROW($1:$31),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$31),2)+1),10)),10)=0), "✔", "❌")), 1, 1))`

In English it checks if H2 contains a valid credit card (passing Luhn's algorithm, discussion / sample data [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1589622/excel-formula-to-test-if-15-or-16-digit-number-is-a-valid-credit-card-and-return)).  The expected output is valid = ✔; invalid = ❌; if blank then nothing.

I'm trying to adjust this to appear in every row, but can't seem to nail it down.  (Using the trick like for a formula `=LEFT(H2,4)&" "&MID(H2,5,6)`, if it's `=arrayformula(LEFT(H2:H100,4)&" "&MID(H2:H100,5,6))` it appears in every row without having to manually refill it when a new row is inserted).

[Sample google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ihArcgxYcMf0ZUqsbBH3SeuYcW9F0dJ9oTnWQXtuXQ8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: if you could provide a sample sheet with a bit of data, it would make it much easier to work on this.

Comment: Added https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ihArcgxYcMf0ZUqsbBH3SeuYcW9F0dJ9oTnWQXtuXQ8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    H2:H = "",
      "",
      IF(
        MOD(
          MMULT(
              MID(REPT("0", 20 - LEN(H2:H)) & H2:H, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 2, 2), 1)
            + MID(REPT("0", 20 - LEN(H2:H)) & H2:H, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 1, 2), 1) * 2
            - (MID(REPT("0", 20 - LEN(H2:H)) & H2:H, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 1, 2), 1) * 2 > 9) * 9,
            SEQUENCE(10, 1, 1, 0)
          ),
          10
        ) = 0,
          "✔",
          "❌"
      )
  )
)
```

[image]

If you want a more general solution (for card numbers longer than 20 digits), replace 20 with `MAX(LEN(H2:H)) + MOD(MAX(LEN(H2:H)), 2)`, and 10 with `(MAX(LEN(H2:H)) + MOD(MAX(LEN(H2:H)), 2)) / 2`.